# azure speech to text service call

Tags: java, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have audio file, and want to invoke client sdk to speech to text service, so that text content can be returned.
Is there any demo so that I can start quickly?

```
<dependency
   <groupId>com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech</groupId>
   <artifactId>client-sdk</artifactId>
   <version>1.28.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet you have tried in the question

Comment: I converted speech to text with Java code, the output looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/poDPzdn.png).

Comment: I used com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech client-sdk 1.28.0 dependency in [pom.xml](https://i.imgur.com/YDSOuYi.png).

Answer (score 0):

***I tried below java code to convert speech-to-text with audio file.***

**Code:**

```java
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.*;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.AudioConfig;

public class SpeechToTextDemo {
        private static String speechSubscriptionKey = "<key>";
        private static String serviceRegion = "<region>";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                String audioFile = "<path/to/audio-wav-file>";
                AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(audioFile);

                SpeechConfig speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(speechSubscriptionKey, serviceRegion);
                SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

                System.out.println("Recognizing...");
                SpeechRecognitionResult result = recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync().get();

                System.out.println("Recognized text: " + result.getText());

                recognizer.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

My project structure looks like below, I added **1 audio wav file** to get output as text,

[image]

**Dependencies:**

```java
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Output:**

***It runs successfully and got output as below,***

[image]

**Reference:**
Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windows,terminal&pivots=programming-language-java) to know more about Speech-To-Text
conversions.